# MVC Code First Database Without Data: Where is the Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Got three simple classes

```
namespace MVC_Risk.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string SrcSys { get; set; }
        public string CustumerID { get; set; }
        public string CustNm { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MVC_Risk.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string SrcSys { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string AccountID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Balance> Balances { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customers { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MVC_Risk.Models
{
    public class Balance
    {
        public int BalanceID { get; set; }
        public int EntryNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime RepDt { get; set; }
        public string SrcSys { get; set; }
        public string CustIdX { get; set; }
        public string CustNm { get; set; }
        public string AccountID { get; set; }
        public string BrId { get; set; }
        public string SegId { get; set; }
        public string ProdId { get; set; }
        public decimal? PrOs { get; set; }
        public decimal? MupRec { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Attempting to learn Fluent API auto-generated keys concept.

Context File:

```
namespace MVC_Risk.DAL
{
    public class RiskContext : DbContext
    {
        public RiskContext() : base("RiskyConnectionString")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers;
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts;
        public DbSet<Balance> Balances;
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Initializer File (Requiring a clean Database (i.e. without data):

```
namespace MVC_Risk.DAL
{
    public class RiskyInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<RiskContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(RiskContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RiskyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=RiskyDatabase1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
    <context type="MVC_Risk.DAL.RiskContext, MVC_Risk">
      <databaseInitializer type="MVC_Risk.DAL.RiskyInitializer, MVC_Risk" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Upon Building and running the site launches but database not found on (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB?

Answer (score 2):

Did you run your initial [Entity Framework Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the question Bill. Went through the referred topic. However, why to run the same when the same isn't mentioned in the ASP's **Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5**? Besides that won't it create and **migrate** too on SQL? While I wan't it to be created and run on the Local